# setting date and time using push buttons

Tags: c

Hello guys i am trying to write a program that i can use a push switch(GPIO) to set date and time so basically after setting the time it should keep on counting just as a normal time would am going to use a nucleo board-f746zg(os.mbed platform) but i haven't got an idea how to do that i would appreciate it very much if any one could give me an idea on how to do it please even if its small i would appreciate it. i found this code below but i don't know how it really works.

```
/*********************************************************************/
void set_clock()
{   unsigned char i;  
    unsigned char temp;      //temp is used to hold a value specifying which digit we are changing
    temp=1;                      //start with HOUR
    i=1;
    lcd_clear();                 //clear display
    lcd_goto(0x40);           //go to second row
    lcd_puts(mSet);          //display user message
    //must convert values to decimal for displaying since they are in Binary Coded Decimal format used in the RTC
    rtc_hour=myBCD2DEC(rtc_hour);
    rtc_min=myBCD2DEC(rtc_min);
    rtc_month=myBCD2DEC(rtc_month);
    rtc_date=myBCD2DEC(rtc_date);
    rtc_year=myBCD2DEC(rtc_year);
    rtc_day=myBCD2DEC(rtc_day);
    update_time();             //display time/date on LCD

    while(!Middle_Switch){};        //wait for button to be released

    while(i){
    if(!Middle_Switch){
        ++temp;
        DelayMs(200);
        while(!Middle_Switch){};        //wait for button to be released
    }; 
    switch(temp) {
        case 1: //Hour
            if (!Right_Switch){
                ++rtc_hour;
                if(rtc_hour>23){rtc_hour=0;};
                DelayMs(200);           //delay to De-Bounce switch
            }
            else if (!Left_Switch){
                if(rtc_hour==0){
                    rtc_hour=23;}
                else{
                    --rtc_hour;
                };
                DelayMs(200);
            };
            break;
        case 2: //Minutes
            if (!Right_Switch){
                ++rtc_min;
                if(rtc_min>59){rtc_min=0;};
                DelayMs(200);
            }
            else if (!Left_Switch){
                if(rtc_min==0){
                    rtc_min=59;}
                else{
                    --rtc_min;
                };
                DelayMs(200);
            };
            break;
        case 3: //Month
            if (!Right_Switch){
                ++rtc_month;
                if(rtc_month>12){rtc_month=1;};
                DelayMs(200);
            }
            else if (!Left_Switch){
                if(rtc_month==1){
                    rtc_month=12;}
                else{
                    --rtc_month;
                };
                DelayMs(200);
            };
            break;
        case 4: //Date
            if (!Right_Switch){
                ++rtc_date;
                if(rtc_date>31){rtc_date=1;};
                DelayMs(200);
            }
            else if (!Left_Switch){
                if(rtc_date==1){
                    rtc_date=31;}
                else{
                    --rtc_date;
                };
                DelayMs(200);
            };
            break;
        case 5: //year
            if (!Right_Switch){
                ++rtc_year;
                if(rtc_year>99){rtc_year=0;};
                DelayMs(200);
            }
            else if (!Left_Switch){
                if(rtc_year==0){
                    rtc_year=99;}
                else{
                    --rtc_year;
                };
                DelayMs(200);
            };
            break;
        case 6: //day of week (sunday = 1)
            if (!Right_Switch){
                ++rtc_day;
                if(rtc_day>7){rtc_day=1;};
                DelayMs(200);
            }
            else if (!Left_Switch){
                if(rtc_day==1){
                    rtc_day=7;}
                else{
                    --rtc_day;
                };
                DelayMs(200);
            };
            break;
        case 7:
            //convert settings back to BCD
            rtc_hour=myDEC2BCD(rtc_hour);
            rtc_min=myDEC2BCD(rtc_min);
            rtc_sec=0;
            rtc_month=myDEC2BCD(rtc_month);
            rtc_date=myDEC2BCD(rtc_date);
            rtc_year=myDEC2BCD(rtc_year);
            rtc_day=myDEC2BCD(rtc_day);
            //save all settings back to registers
            write_clk_regs();
            i=0;       
            break;
        };//end switch
        update_time();
    };//end while
}//end set clock
/*********************************************************************/
//Function used to display the date/time on 2x16 LCD//
void update_time()
{   lcd_goto(0x00);
    sprintf(LCD_Buffer,"%2d:%2d %2d|%2d|%2d %d",rtc_hour,rtc_min,rtc_month,rtc_date,rtc_year,rtc_day);
    lcd_puts(LCD_Buffer);
}
/*********************************************************************/
```

Comment: Please more information. e.g. platform, OS, are the buttons GPIOs etc..

Comment: @gj13 i have updated it

Comment: Hmm. always tag sensibly to attract the relevant audience.  :)

Comment: If you are using the C/C++ language, please tag your question with the C/C++ tag. C and C++ tags are not appropriate here, they are for C and C++ languages respectively.

Comment: Since you are using the C++ tag, you should consider using `std::stringstream` instead of `sprintf`.  The `sprintf` has the possibility of overflowing buffers.

Comment: C++ tag deleted as nothing about this post hints at C++